# How to gain specific field value manually in django admin fieldsets

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm overriding `admin/includes/app-name/fieldset.html` to change the behavior of some fields using the JavaScript.

In the original fieldset.html by django theres a loop to display the fields, But I want to pick the value of first field for some usecase. How can I do that

```
 # I removed some code to make it simpler to read
    {% for line in fieldset %}
                {% for field in line %}
                    {{ field.field }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

I'm trying

```
 {{ fieldset[0].field }}
```

But this gives the error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[1].field' from 'fieldset[1].field'
```

If i do that

```
{{ fieldset }}
```

This gives

```
<django.contrib.admin.helpers.Fieldset object at 0x000002873F9B1940>
```

How I can Pick the data of first field instead of running a loop, means I do not need iteration here, Just wants to pick values manually. I'm not fully aware of django template tags. So your help would be needed here.

Comment: Try using `{{fieldset.0.field}}` You can't use brackets, `fieldset[0]`, in templates

Comment: That returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### See Edit, this is wrong

I believe it would be this: `{{fieldset.0.0.field}}`

---

##### Thought Process:

`{% for line in fieldset %}` means **fieldset** is an List
`{% for field in line %}` means **line** is an List

So we're looking at something like:

```py
    fieldset = [
        [fieldObj0, fieldObj1],     # Line 0
        [fieldObj2, fieldObj3],     # Line 1
    ]
```

Get Line 0 (first line):
`{{fieldset.0}}` = `[fieldObj0, fieldObj1]`

Get first fieldObj in Line 0:
`{{fieldset.0.0}}` = `fieldObj0`

Get field attribute of the first fieldObj in the first line
`{{fieldset.0.0.field}}` = `fieldObj0.field`

Hopefully that's correct (*it was not)*

---

### Edit

##### Two Solutions

**Manually Fetching field by Name:** `{{fieldset.form.actual_field_name_here}}`

- Lose the dynamic part of *first field*

**Using Counter in Loop**

```html
    {% for line in fieldset %}
        {% for field in line %}

            {% if forloop.parentloop.first and forloop.first %}
                first line + first field: {{ field.field }}
            {% else %}
                {{ field.field }}
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

#### Things I've learned

After looking at the source code, fieldset actually uses an `__iter__` method and that's why my original stuff didn't work.
And What is *extra* annoying is they create the Fieldline Object **in** the `__iter__` method instead of just generating them beforehand and throwing it into an attribute. This means the only way you can access those objects is **during** the loop.  This extends to the Fieldline object which does the same thing with `AdminField`

###### contrib\admin\helpers.py

```py
class Fieldset:
    def __init__(self, form, name=None, readonly_fields=(), fields=(), classes=(),
                 description=None, model_admin=None):

        self.form = form                        # Is Django Form
        self.name, self.fields = name, fields   # Fields is an array of strings

        ## more stuff - chopped out
        

    def __iter__(self):
        for field in self.fields:
            yield Fieldline(self.form, field, self.readonly_fields, model_admin=self.model_admin)


class Fieldline:
    def __init__(self, form, field, readonly_fields=None, model_admin=None):
        self.form = form  # A django.forms.Form instance
        if not hasattr(field, "__iter__") or isinstance(field, str):
            self.fields = [field]
        else:
            self.fields = field

        ## more stuff - chopped out

    def __iter__(self):
        for i, field in enumerate(self.fields):
            if field in self.readonly_fields:
                yield AdminReadonlyField(self.form, field, is_first=(i == 0), model_admin=self.model_admin)
            else:
                yield AdminField(self.form, field, is_first=(i == 0))
```

Comment: Yeah I tried, But that also returns none. If I change the field.field to field.field.value in the loop it gives the values but Idk why its not working with `{{fieldset.0.0.field}}` or `{{fieldset.0.0.field.value}}`

Comment: I looked at the source code, played around with my own project and I found a solution. See my edit, and I explained my findings (if you're interested)